# React Router v4 redirect to authenticated route when user successfully signIn

Tags: reactjs, jwt, reactjs-flux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am newbie for react and migrated from angular and trying to implement a simple JWT authenticated Flux react app with Route v4. I have successfully send request to Rails API and got my JWT token. Now I couldn't find any programmatically logical way to redirect my app to the authenticated Route component in LoginAction.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {  BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import AuthenticatedApp from './components/AuthenticatedApp';

const app = document.getElementById('root');


ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Layout} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="/record" component={AuthenticatedApp} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
app);

registerServiceWorker();
```

LoginAction.js

In my LoginAction after a successful request to api with valid token I want to redirect the page to AuthenticatedApp component. Since there was only reference to older version of routes however Route 4 version have very few support in internet.

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatchers/AppDispatcher.js';
import LOGIN_USER from '../constants/LoginConstants';
import LOGOUT_USER from '../constants/LoginConstants';
import RouterContainer from '../services/RouterContainer'

export default {
    loginUser: (jwt) => {
    var savedJwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType:LOGIN_USER,
            jwt: jwt
        });
        if (savedJwt !== jwt) {

            {want to redirect to '/record' of AuthenticatedAPP component}

            localStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt);
        }
    },

    logoutUser: () => {
        RouterContainer.get().transitionEnter('/home');
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType:LOGOUT_USER
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, I have not still found what would be the replacement for these `getCurrentQuery(),` `transitionTo` in Route v4.

Answer (score 1):

React Router v4 has a [Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) component. If there is a valid jwt, you could redirect to the authenticated part of the app. Something like

```
// drop this in your render()

const path = yourIsLoggedInCheck ? '/loggedInHome' : '/login';
<Redirect to={path} />;
```

Just make sure you're still doing auth checks in the logged in part of your app.

> Finally, I have not still found what would be the replacement for
>   these getCurrentQuery()

You can use the [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) higher order component to grab your query string data. Wrapping your component will give you access to a `location` prop.

```
// let's say you're looking for a query string param called myParam

// ...
  let myParam = null;
  if (this.props.location.search) {
    myParam = location.search.split('myParam=')[1].split('&')[0] || null;
  }
// ...

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```